# Change image source when scale greater than x, using 2 functions in React?

Tags: reactjs, image, function, scale

I'm currently trying to change the source of my image according to its scale but I can't get it to work.

I have a function that loads my 2 images and a function that changes the scale, but I can't correlate them.

So I would like to use my "testScale" in the **change()** function to change the source of my image in the **loadImage()** function.

At the moment I assign the "img" source to my "image" state in the **loadImage()** function and I would like to assign the "imgFull" source when my "testScale" reaches a certain value.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks for your help

These are my 2 functions:

**loadImage:**

```
loadImages = (frames, size) => {
        this.setState({
            ready: false,
            loaded: 0
        })
        for (let i = 0; i < this.numberOfFrames; i += 1) {
            const {images, testScale} = this.state
            const img = new Image()
            const imgFull = new Image()
            img.onload = () => {
                const {loaded} = this.state
                this.setState({loaded: loaded + 1, ready: loaded + 1 >= this.numberOfFrames})
            }
            imgFull.onload = () => {
                const {loaded} = this.state
                this.setState({loaded: loaded + 1, ready: loaded + 1 >= this.numberOfFrames})
            }
            imgFull.src = frames[i].replace('1920', 3840)
            img.src = frames[i].replace('1920', size)
            images[i] = img
            this.setState({images})
            console.log(images)
        }
    }
```

**change:**

```
    change = (event, value) => {
        const {initialScale} = this.state
        let finalValue = value
        if (value == null || value === 'undefined') {
            finalValue = 0.5
            console.log(value)
        } else if (value < initialScale) {
            finalValue = initialScale
        }
        this.setState({
            testScale: finalValue
        })
    }
```

Comment: can you create a stackblitz fiddle or post the full working code

Comment: @AkhilAravind unfortunately, I can't post all the application code but I can post the component code.

Comment: thats what I mean, please post the component code with html markup\

Comment: Bro just dont post the whole code, just post a minimal reproducing code for your issue